# IOException: stream closed error while reading multiple files from HDFS

Tags: java, io, hdfs

I'm getting a strange error while trying to read some job configuration files from HDFS. I'm trying to retrieve the jobs from a file, then reading their job configuration XML files in a loop.

Excerpt:

```
for(JobStatus status : statuses)
{
    JobID jobId = null;
    try
    {
        jobId = status.getJobID(); //TODO check the hash-code/equals implementation of JobID
        if(!jobIdsUnderObservation.contains(jobId))
        { //explore jobs if it's new
            RunningJob runningJob = jobClient.getJob(jobId);
            if(runningJob != null)
            {
                String jobFile = runningJob.getJobFile();
                FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);
                if(fs.exists(new Path(jobFile)))
                {
                    String sessionId = null;
                    InputStream is = fs.open(new Path(jobFile));
                    conf.addResource(is);
                    sessionId = conf.get("hive.session.id"); //this particular line breaks 
                    //from the second file onwards 
                    if(sessionId.equals(this.sessionId))
                    {
                        jobIdsUnderObservation.add(jobId);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
    int prevStatus = 0;
```

It reads the first file fine, but it breaks from the second file onward. It throws an IOException: stream closed.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the xml readers close the underlying streams when its close method is called. This is not what they say in the documentation, but it is in the release notes...

To avoid this behaviour you could override the close method of the reader or wrap the stream into another class.

I reported that to sun years ago, but it is "too risky to fix"

https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6539065

(There are some examples there)

Comment: Thanks Victor! I'm just trying to figure out why the problem starts appearing from the second file onward.

Comment: @Subhasis You're wellcome, try to debug and see who is calling to the close method of your stream.